# Determining Lag for Granger Causality

Tags: time-series, aic, bic, lags, granger-causality

I am trying to understand how to identify lag length to use for a Granger Causality test.  The process as I understand it is:

1. Use an information criterion such as AIC or BIC to calculate the number of lags to use for each time series.
2. Choose the larger of the two lags.

I am having trouble understanding how you do step 1 of this process.  I program in Python, and am trying to implement this process into code.

Comment: Have you read Dave Gile's blog posts on testing Granger causality? (They will not help you with coding but with lag order selection.)

Comment: You can have a look at this document: http://www.stat.wisc.edu/courses/st333-larget/aic.pdf
It shows how to do the implementation in R, but the idea should be easily portable to Python.

Comment: There are good sources. [This](https://davegiles.blogspot.com/2011/04/testing-for-granger-causality.html) one is the tutorial explaining the algorithm step by step on how to perform granger causality, all the tests which are needed to determine if X granger causes Y and vice-versa. And [this](https://rishi-a.github.io/2020/05/25/granger-causality.html) one its the same steps implemented in python.

Answer (score 2):

Partially answered in comments:

Have you read Dave Gile's blog posts on testing Granger causality? (They will not help you with coding but with lag order selection.) – Richard Hardy
https://davegiles.blogspot.com/2011/04/testing-for-granger-causality.html

You can have a look at this document: http://www.stat.wisc.edu/courses/st333-larget/aic.pdf It shows how to do the implementation in R, but the idea should be easily portable to Python. – Matthias Schmidtblaicher

Comment: The second link you provided doesn't work anymore. Would you happen to know what it has changed to?

Comment: @altabq: Cannot find it, maybe a replacement:  https://www.r-bloggers.com/chicken-or-the-egg-granger-causality-for-the-masses/

Comment: Thanks for the link! I've found another blog explaining the procedure in R. Posting it for reference: https://datazen.info/toda-yamamoto-implementation-in-r/

Comment: I do not think this answers the question in a good manner. Just giving a couple of links without summarizing their content would better fit as a comment. And since the content is already posted as comments, I do not see this answer as particularly helpful.

Comment: @RichardHardy: Maybe, but the point of summarizing comments as an answer is so the Q do not linger on as *unanswered*.  See  much discussion on meta, https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/etiquette-for-answering-old-questions-addressed-in-comments,  https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5402/is-a-quick-and-dirty-answer-better-than-no-answer

Comment: I skimmed through the threads but did not find an argument for posting answers like this. There is no problem with a short answer or one based on comments, but it should answer the question. IMHO, just trying to remove a question from the category of unanswered ones does not justify posting a comment or two as an answer. Suppose a new user posts a similar question and it gets closed as a duplicate of this one. Since this one does not actually answer the question (only provides references to external material), that would be unfair. This is just my understanding of the matter.

Comment: Also, it is not uncommon to convert comment-like answers to comments, and I was tempted to flag this one for that reason before I saw that the original comments it is based on are still present. While converting comment-like answers to comments increases the number of questions in the unanswered category, it makes a lot of sense to me. Overall, I do not think the number of questions in the unanswered category should play any role in the discussion of what counts as a good answer and whether a given answer should have been posted in the first place.